# Taking root ownership

Tags: java

Just gonna make this clear first, this is for class!

I have an assignment that requires to 1) modify a web server written in Java to accept file uploads and to use this to deface the homepage (did that no problem).

2) Take root ownership of the machine.

I'm hitting a bit of a wall with the second part.  I used curl with an HTTP GET to traverse to the etc/passwd file but then later found that no passwords are stored here. I know the shadow file has the passwords stored, but I can't access it.  The server kicks back a 404 when I try to, I'm assuming permissions are the issue.

My command for curl looks like this:

```
curl 127.0.0.1:8080/../../../../etc/passwd
```

Although I'm doing this from the same machine that the server is running on, I have to play it as if I don't have access to the server.  Any help in pointing me in the right direction to go from here is appreciated!

Comment: Please review [what is considered on-topic for SF](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). We do not provide assistance with system mis-use, regardless of context.

Comment: But we do (only in certain context)!

Comment: @LucasKauffman The question was migrated from SeverFault.  I think the comment was in regards to what's OT there, not here on security.

Comment: I know, I made them migrate it over here :p

Comment: If you can use curl to get /etc/passwd, then I assume you can also read other file. E.g. ssh keys...

Comment: @Hennes: /etc/passwd is by default world readable

Comment: Aye. But on a modern host it no longer contains passwords. SSH keys on the other hand *should* not be readable, but attempting it is a brazingly direct route which might just work in a home work situation.  (Granted, with part 1 of the exorcise being to upload something I suspect that installing a local shell might be the way to go. But you can always try to upload a new ssh config, or another service config.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are different ways to go about this. First of all I would advice you to upload a shell onto the web server which allows for interactive bash commands. There are tons of them out there, not sure if there is one for java. If you don't find one just create a simple script which performs a reverse TCP shell bind to your IP (you can use netcat, if you aren't familiar with netcat lookup some tutorials).

From here you already have some easier control so you can go looking in files for interesting content. Check the logs for usernames/passwords and go looking for executables with the SUID bit set. Also try to find out what other services are running (these might be exploitable) so make a nice service enumeration. Make sure to check the version of the kernel when you are on there as it might be possible to create a local root exploit (check exploit-db and google).

Comment: You might want to watch this video too, it details a handful of InfoSec tools you might use for your assignment -> http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/Europe/2013/ATC-B309

Comment: I'm going to go ahead an accept this as the answer.  I haven't been successful yet, however using scripts seems to so far be the best option.